# How to write powers ( exponents ) in a proper way?

Tags: support, mathjax

I don't how to write the powers or the exponents and the other mathematical expressions

Answer (score 3):

You write exponents like so:

$\$$(base of exponent)^(power)$\$$

For example, 2 to the power of 5 would be written as $\$$2^5$\$$. That looks like $2^5$

I recommend reading the MathJax tutorial for a full guide on how to type these symbols.

http://www.meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: let's try and see .. $5^8$

Comment: thanks ...........

Comment: @Maher: Note that to write exponents longer than a single character, you need to use braces: `2^10` is $2^10$ but `2^{10}` is $2^{10}$. (Of course, you can write $2^{9}$ as `2^{9}` as well.)

Comment: How do you do a paper to a negative letter? I.e. 5 to the power of minus $t$? Thanks.

Comment: You write it as $5^{-t}$.

Comment: @PabloIvan Could provide the MathJax code for negative powers?

Comment: The code is 5^{-t}

Comment: \$5^{2}\$ is the way to write exponents, $5^{2}$ .